# When calling a function, why do I get these errors?

Tags: c

I get these warnings that I believe are preventing anything from printing:
"passing argument 1 of 'printboard' makes pointer from integer without a cast" when I call the function and "expected char(*)[26] but argument is of type 'char'" on line 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printBoard(char board[26][26], int n){
int i,j,k;

if (i=0){
        for (j=1;j<n;j++){
        for (k=1;k<n;k++){
            board[i][j]=k;
        }
        printf("%c", k+96);
    }
}

if (j=0){
for(i=1;i<n;i++){
    for(k=1;k<n;j++){
        board[i][j]=k;
        printf("%c", k+96);
    }
}    
}

for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for (j=1;j<=n;j++){
        if (board[i][j]!=board[n/2][n/2]&&board[i][j]!=board[(n/2)+1][(n/2)+1]&&board[i][j]!=board[n/2][(n/2)+1]&&board[i][j]!=board[(n/2)+1][n/2]){
            board[i][j]='U';
        }
        else if (board[i][j]==board[n/2][n/2]&&board[i][j]==board[(n/2)+1][(n/2)+1]){
            board[i][j]='W';
        }
        else {
            board[i][j]='B';
        }
    }
    printf("%c", board[i][j]);
}
//n is even
return;
}


int main(void)
{
const char board[26][26];
int dim;
char boardConfig;
printf("Enter the board dimension: \n");
scanf("%d", &dim);   

printBoard(board[26][26],dim);
```

Comment: just `printBoard(board,dim);`

Comment: You should generally believe what the compiler is telling you... trying to regard a char value as though it was a pointer is sure to bust up your printing code.

Comment: It would help to know what you are trying to achieve, and what you are hoping to do when populating the board. In a couple of places you have written code like `if (i=0) { ... }` but this is wrong (a single equals vs double equals). And if you want to initialize `i` to zero before that then do it explicitly.

Comment: i'm trying to print a reversi gameboard, where B and W are colours of the pieces and U represents an unoccupied space.

Answer (score 1):

`board[26][26]` is a `char` element (out of bounds). You want to pass the entire 2D array board:

```
printBoard(board,dim);
```

(also: check return code of `scanf`, and check if `dim` is within 1-26 bounds to avoid undefined behaviour)

And when initializing `board[i][j]=k;` add some ASCII offset (ex: `board[i][j]=k+'a';`). Otherwise, your code will print non-ASCII characters at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You need to typecast it to the parameter type. There are a number of errors in your code - such as the assignment operators instead of comparison operators. `if(i=0)` should be `if(i==0)`, etc. I got the code compiled and working, not certain as to what you are trying to do yet, but this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printBoard(char board[26][26], int n){
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;

if (i==0){
        for (j=1;j<n;j++){
        for (k=0;k<n;k++){
            board[i][j]=k;
        }
        printf("%c", k+96);
    }
}

if (j==0){
for(i=1;i<n;i++){
    for(k=0;k<n;k++){
        board[i][j]=k;
        printf("%c", k+96);
    }
}    
}

for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for (j=1;j<=n;j++){
        if (board[i][j]!=board[n/2][n/2]&&board[i][j]!=board[(n/2)+1][(n/2)+1]&&board[i][j]!=board[n/2][(n/2)+1]&&board[i][j]!=board[(n/2)+1][n/2]){
            board[i][j]='U';
        }
        else if (board[i][j]==board[n/2][n/2]&&board[i][j]==board[(n/2)+1][(n/2)+1]){
            board[i][j]='W';
        }
        else {
            board[i][j]='B';
        }
    }
    printf("%c", board[i][j]);
}
//n is even
return;
}


int main(void)
{
const char board[26][26];
int dim;
char boardConfig;
printf("Enter the board dimension: \n");
scanf("%d", &dim);   

printBoard((char (*)[26])board,dim);
}
```

Comment: The cast is unnecessary if you change `printBoard(board[26][26]` to `printBoard(board`.

Comment: I'm trying to print a reversi gameboard, where W and B represent colours for the pieces, and U represents an unoccupied space.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Yes, you still need the cast if you do what you said. First thing I did - what I thought it was. You actually need to cast it the way that I did in order for it to be able to compile. Please give me an upvote, and double check that you are correct when down voting in the future please.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. I do need to double-check that I'm correct before downvoting. Maybe instead you should remove the `const` on `const char board[26][26];` so you don't need the cast. It looks like `board` is being modified in another function so that's probably undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it is the const.